# ThreadLocal sharing data?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters, thread-local, esapi

By all means I know the following is not possible, but it is occurring in one of our production environments:

**SETUP**

- ESAPI 2.01
- Main servlet filter setting and removing a current request thread local object:

  ```
  try {
      ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(request, response);

      // filter logic ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(Logger.SECURITY_FAILURE, "Error in ESAPI "
              + "security filter: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      request.setAttribute("message", e.getMessage());
  } finally {
      ESAPI.clearCurrent();
  }
  ```

all requests pass through this filter, and `ESAPI.currentRequest()` is used throughout the system.

- Path A (`http://server/path_a/`)

  - goes through until it reaches `method_a`, this method is not accessible from `path_b`
- Path B (`http://server/path_b`)

  - goes through until it reaches `method_b`, not accessible from `path_a`

Both of these paths go through the servlet filter (mapping "`/*`")

One of our error mails that I received suggests that `path_a` is throwing an error, which in turn initiates the error mail, in the mail code, the current request (via `ESAPI.currentRequest()`) is enumerated for request info.

**PROBLEM**

In the error mail, request info from `path_a` correlates with stacktrace info from `method_b`, to me this seems impossible as both run in separate threads.

**QUESTION**

How is this possible? I cannot re-create this locally, are their certain precautions I have to take other than setting and clearing the `ThreadLocal`? Can this be a problem with tomcat setup? I'm lost.

---

<sub>PS: code from the question has been simplified as the code base is to large for an example</sub>

---

[image: error mail]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the filter, but looking at it from a different angle, how is the e-mail composed? Does the filter do this for you or might there be some code their that is not thread-safe?

Comment: the error mail method is called from a singleton object, in the method, `ESAPI.currentRequest()` is used to enumerate the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading ESAPI code https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultHTTPUtilities.java there are some questionable practices regarding thread local.

The biggest problem I'd say is it uses `InheritableThreadLocal`. If thread A spawns a thread B, B will inherit A's thread local value; however, when A then clears the thread local, it doesn't affect B, so B's inherited value will stay. ESAPI probably shouldn't use `InheritableThreadLocal`.

I can't say how this may produce the problem you see, without knowing more about threads in your app.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I checked the code and the email building task was submitted to a `ExecutorService`, so when it ran it used an outdated request? can you clarify on the workings? Should I open a ticket with ESAPI?

Comment: The task is likely dispatched to an existing thread that was spawned from a different thread, therefore inheriting the thread local request from that thread. the request info should be generated on this thread before submitting the email task. And for ESAPI, I think it is definitely a mistake to use InheritableThreadLocal.